# Force Doxygen to pop warnings if uncommented C++ methods

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am trying to make doxygen pop warnings for missing documentation with a C++ project.
I tried to put in the Doxyfile

```
WARNINGS               = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
```

I also tried:

```
WARNINGS               = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
# (WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED is ignored if EXTRACT_ALL is enabled)
```

But nothing happens.

What I don't understand is that if I put uncomplete Doxygen comments on the `printArgs` method, I do get a warning saying that some parameters are not documented, but if I don't put the doxygen tags, I get no warnings.

Which Doxyfile field can enable this feature ? This is a minimal example, I want to use this warning feature in a Jenkins server to check that all methods and fields have been documented.

my code to test is very simple:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    cout << "Hello World !" << endl;
    printArgs(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << "Arg #" << argc << " : " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

**test.h** NOT generating warnings

```
#pragma once

void printArgs(int argc, char **argv);
```

**test.h** generating warnings (tag for 'argv' is missing)

```
#pragma once
/**
 * @brief 
 * 
 * @param argc 
 */
void printArgs(int argc, char **argv);
```

**EDIT:**

I found a solution that partially solves my problem:

From [Doxygen's `\file` command documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html):

> The documentation of global functions, variables, typedefs, and enums
> will only be included in the output if the file they are in is
> documented as well or if EXTRACT_ALL is set to YES.

And from the Doxyfile's `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED` comment :

> If EXTRACT_ALL is set to YES then this flag will automatically be disabled.

So what I want is having both `EXTRACT_ALL` and `WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED` set to true **which is not possible**.

I don't understand why it's not possible, and if someone has an explanation, I'd be grateful. The only work around for me was to put `/** \file */` at the top of `test.h`.

This doesn't solve my problem fully because I want to track missing comments with this "feature" and the missing comments could be the `/** \file */` as well and if it is the case I am screwed...

Comment: At the moment this is not possible due to the fact that EXTRACT_ALL is very stringent regarding filtering out warnings. I created created a proposed pull request for doxygen (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8073) to give more warnings (can be quite a lot of warnings though).